# Why does `git log --all` show removed commits?

Tags: git, git-log

I used `git reset --hard sha` on a commit to strip/remove several commits, then did `git gc --prune=now`.  When I do a `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` it returns commits with the latest at the sha I used in the reset command.  This is what I’m expecting.

However, I then did `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all` and it is returning commits I thought I stripped.  Why is this history still here?

ETA: None of these commits exist on a master repo

Comment: Run `git for-each-ref --contains $removedsha` to print all the refs from which the removed commit is reachable.

Answer (score 6):

This is one of those cases where splitting hairs may actually be important.

When you say you "stripped" some commits, that's imprecise.  To be more specific, you removed those commits *from the history of the branch that was checked out when you gave the `reset` command*.  If any other ref (another branch, a tag, the current stash, various other things) could reach those commits, then it still can.

The `--all` option to `git log` says to show the history of all refs - not just the current branch (from which you removed the commits).  You might be able to use the output of `git log --graph --all` to sort out which ref(s) still reach your commits.  If you can use `gitk` in your environment, that may be a better visualization.

As an additional note, your `gc` attempt would've failed even if no refs could still reach the commits in question, because the reflogs can still reach them.  After moving all refs so that nothing "knows" of those commits any more, you'll also have to expire any affected reflogs.

Answer (score 0):

The `git log` command works by starting from some particular commit or set of commits, whose IDs are eventually raw OIDs,<sup>1</sup> and then working backwards through the commit graph.<sup>2</sup>  The OIDs come from arguments given to `git log`; with no OID arguments and no substitutes for them, the default is to look up `HEAD` as an OID.  So this:

> When I do a `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` it returns commits with the latest at the sha I used in the reset command. This is what I’m expecting.

is fine.  (Note by the way that `--oneline` is short for `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`, so you might want to use this to shorten your command line sequence.)

> However, I then did `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit —-all` and it is returning commits I thought I stripped. Why is this history still here?

The `--all` option pretends that all `refs/` entries (all references: all branch names, tag names, and other special names that are not the `HEAD` or `*_HEAD` special names) were specified on the command line.  One or more of those refs must resolve to, or lead to, the hash you thought you stripped.

It's not unusual for `refs/stash` to do this, for instance, or for some other branch name to do this.

You can run `git for-each-ref` with no arguments at all to list out all the refs that `--all` implies.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's best not to call these "SHA" now as other hash algorithms are allowed, at least in theory.  It's true that the upcoming change is to use SHA2-256, which is still an SHA hash, but the internal Git term is now OID, or Object ID.

<sup>2</sup>With `-g` (`--walk-reflogs`), the walk is through the reflog rather than the commit graph.  With `--no-walk` the walk itself is suppressed, so that you get only the initially-selected OIDs.